# Basis of Lambda algebra for a programmer

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, lie-algebras, spectral-sequences, derived-functors

First of all, I'm not a specialist in alg. top., but I try to apply computational math to it, so if I'm wrong in something you'd be doing a better thing explaining it to me instead of blaming me :) What I want is to write a code for calculating homotopies of Lie groups, which I do according to [1] through combinatorial computation of allowable sets (Section 4) defining derived functors applied to Lie group (Theorems 5.3, 6.2). Further, I try to interpret elements of allowable set as generators of homotopy group according to [2] Section 7 or [3]. All expressions in allowable sets are made of $\lambda$'s and $\mu$'s. If Lie functor was graded by a power of 2, $\lambda$'s are enough for finishing my task, and I just implement them by definition from [2] "The Ring $\Lambda$" and [2] "Composition (7.8)" to compose them. I have done the code for this part [4] (check `lambdaUnit` for definition of $\lambda$ and `lambda` for composition — they repeat what [2] says in Section 2). But computation of $\mu$ is challenging to me, because [3] consider only $p = 2$, and therefore $\lambda$, in details while saying that $\mu$ is its natural generalisation (really, just "Let the operations 1 and 2 be defined in the
obvious manner" on page 341) without constructions, which are needed for a kettle like me. Precisely, I need the analogue of formulas from [2] "Composition (7.8)", "Shuffles (7.10)" and understanding, the homotopy class of which element in $L_p^u K(m)$ is represented by each $\mu_i$ to finish my code for $p > 2$ and be happy. I would be very grateful if you can show me the example of how one can obtain such a results, or if you give me instructions of how I can do it by myself, taking into account that I'm newbie in alg. top. and prefer explicit constructions than intuition in this field :) Thank you in advance.

[1] ROMAN MIKHAILOV "HOMOTOPY THEORY OF LIE FUNCTORS" https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.00681.pdf

[2] Curtis "Simplicial homotopy theory"

[3] BOWFIELD et al. "THE mod-p LOWER CENTRAL SERIES AND THE ADAMS SPECTRAL SEQUENCE" https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=05D88A427A0DD5E87F9CCD8859BDEF4F?doi=10.1.1.258.7424&rep=rep1&type=pdf

[4] My code https://github.com/dmivilensky/Lambda-algebra-tools/blob/main/lambda.hs